# apache iceberg table - difference between serializable vs snapshot isolation

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-iceberg

I am trying to ingest data into iceberg table using spark streaming. There are no multiple writers to same data at the moment. According to [iceberg api](https://iceberg.apache.org/javadoc/0.11.0/org/apache/iceberg/IsolationLevel.html#:%7E:text=Both%20of%20them%20provide%20a,environments%20with%20many%20concurrent%20writers.) default isolation level for table is `serializable` . I want to understand if there is only a single application (single spark streaming job in my case) writing to iceberg table is there any advantage or disadvantage over using `serializable` or a `snapshot` isolation ? Is there any performance impact of using `serializable` when only one application is writing to table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantages of Serializable Isolation:

Consistent and predictable behavior: Serializable isolation provides the highest level of isolation, guaranteeing that transactions behave as if they are executed serially. It ensures a consistent and predictable outcome, preventing data inconsistencies and anomalies.

Avoidance of concurrency-related issues: Serializable isolation eliminates phenomena such as dirty reads, non-repeatable reads, and phantom reads that can occur in lower isolation levels. It prevents concurrent transactions from interfering with each other's data access, ensuring data integrity.

Disadvantages of Serializable Isolation:

Reduced concurrency: Serializable isolation often requires exclusive locks or optimistic concurrency control mechanisms, which can lead to increased contention and reduced concurrency. This can impact the system's scalability and performance in highly concurrent environments.

Increased transaction aborts: In serializable isolation, transactions may need to be aborted and retried more frequently due to conflicts with concurrent transactions. This can lead to increased overhead and potentially impact application performance.

Advantages of Snapshot Isolation:

Increased concurrency: Snapshot isolation allows concurrent transactions to operate on separate consistent snapshots of the data. This reduces contention and allows for higher concurrency, enabling better scalability in multi-user environments.

Improved performance: With snapshot isolation, transactions can proceed without acquiring exclusive locks on data that is not being modified. This can lead to improved performance and reduced blocking, as conflicts are resolved based on the isolation level rules.

Disadvantages of Snapshot Isolation:

Non-serializable anomalies: Snapshot isolation may allow non-serializable phenomena like non-repeatable reads and phantom reads. Although these anomalies are generally less frequent than in lower isolation levels, they can still occur and might require application-level logic to handle.

Increased storage requirements: Snapshot isolation typically relies on maintaining multiple versions of data to provide consistent snapshots. This can result in increased storage requirements, especially in systems with high update rates or long-running transactions.

Considering your specific case where there is only one application (single Spark Streaming job) writing to the Iceberg table, the choice between serializable isolation and snapshot isolation depends on the level of data consistency you require and the performance considerations:

Serializable Isolation: If strict data consistency is crucial and you want to ensure that your transactions behave as if they are executed serially, you can stick with the default serializable isolation level. Although there might be some overhead related to lock management, it ensures consistent behavior even if your application scales in the future or if multiple writers are introduced.

Snapshot Isolation: If you prioritize concurrency and potential performance gains, you can consider using snapshot isolation. In your current scenario with a single writer, the impact of non-serializable anomalies is minimal. Snapshot isolation allows for higher concurrency and can potentially improve performance and throughput.